# User resizeable columns in bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, resizable, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a layout that looks a lot like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nAbNm/1/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3></div>
        <div class="span7"></div>
        <div class="span2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the two centre border lines be resizeable by the user. I'm looking to have them snap into place, for instance if you dragged the right column larger it would change the middle column from span7->span6 and the right column from span2->span3.

I'm not sure where to start. I know the code has to remove and add classes, and I could do it with a button in a minute but I don't know how to manipulate the 'click-and-drag'.

Comment: Getting the columns resizable and updating classes is fairly easy, as you know. Doing the math to determine what the new grid classes should be is not so easy. I haven't come across a plugin that does that, either.

Comment: I know this is not exactly what you're looking for, but this might help you, it's resizable column behavior on jQuery: http://www.boxyapp.com/plugins/tables/resizable-table-columns-for-jquery/